# Are questions related to TV (not shows) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This [recent question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/80452/27264) has appeared on the site, which made me curious **if questions related TV technology, media format, channels etc are on-topic or not.** I wasn't sure about this as there are other similarly tagged questions, so I didn't vote to close it.

**Which kind of TV related questions are on-topic here? Are these only limited to shows or there is more?**

Currently, Help Center says that following are off-topic.

> Technology questions about playing content
>
> TV news, sports and current affairs

But this confuses more. Media Format kinda falls under the TV Technology category, but yet there are opened questions on main site regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to think this is ***off-topic*** under the second option in our help section

> Locating or purchasing Movies or TV content
>
> **Technology questions about playing content**
>
> Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of > the title.
>
> TV news, sports and current affairs
>
> A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
>
> Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

Notwithstanding that the question is **too broad** and is asking how and why media providers still provide non-HD channels and how they organise them.

This does not seem to be about media creation and **"Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Movies and TV series"**

Comment: OK. Technology part is clear, but what about this `Are these only limited to shows or there is more?`

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I was looking at the tag applied to the question and all 3 questions are likely off-topic. Perhaps a clean-up / review is required,

Comment: Actually, I am just asking which questions related to TV such as technology, channels, broadcasting technology etc.are on topic. I am not talking about the shows here because these are clearly on-topic except those mentioned in the fourth point in your answer.

Comment: I'd have to see the question...but those sound off-topic.